# Angular routing not working as expected for Login URLs

Tags: angular

I have a project in Angular-15

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'auth',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  { path: 'server-error', component: ServerErrorComponent, data: {breadcrumb: 'Server Error'} },
  { path: 'page-not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent, data: {breadcrumb: 'Page Not Found'} },
  { path: 'forbidden', component: ForbiddenComponent, data: {breadcrumb: 'Forbidden'} },
  {
    path: 'merchant-dashboard',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, LoadMerchantGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./features/merchant/merchant.module').then(m => m.MerchantModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./features/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'admin-dashboard',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, LoadAdminGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./features/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
  },
  { path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'page-not-found', pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

auth-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { NavbarLoginInfoComponent } from './components/navbar-login-info/navbar-login-info.component';
import { ChangePasswordComponent } from './components/change-password/change-password.component';
import { MustChangePasswordComponent } from './components/must-change-password/must-change-password.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './components/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { AdminUserLoginComponent } from './components/admin-user-login/admin-user-login.component';
import { SuperUserLoginComponent } from './components/super-user-login/super-user-login.component';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './components/reset-password/reset-password.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'admin-user-login',
        component: AdminUserLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'super-user-login',
        component: SuperUserLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'must-change-password',
        component: MustChangePasswordComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'change-password',
        component: ChangePasswordComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'navigation-login-info',
        component: NavbarLoginInfoComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'forgot-password',
        component: ForgotPasswordComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'reset-password',
        component: ResetPasswordComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AuthRoutingModule {}
```

By default, the landing page is:

https://testing.com/auth

Which is:

```
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
```

However, I want user to be able to type these on the url:

https://testing.com/auth/super-user-login

```
  {
    path: 'super-user-login',
    component: SuperUserLoginComponent,
  },
```

and

https://testing.com/auth/admin-user-login

```
  {
    path: 'admin-user-login',
    component: AdminUserLoginComponent,
  },
```

But instead of this, whevever https://testing.com/auth/super-user-login and https://testing.com/auth/admin-user-login are typed on the URL, they always redirect back to

https://testing.com/auth

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you make sure to add a ````<router-outlet></router-outlet>````  in AuthComponent HTML file as well?

Answer (score 0):

Go To your **AppModule** and change the **AppRoutingModule** with **AuthRoutingModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AuthRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [...
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `pathMatch: 'full',` in the empty path.
Like this

```
 {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```